# Understanding why numpy make a fork whenever it is imported

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, fork

Whenever I make `import numpy` 11 sub-processes (my CPU has 6/12 cores/threads) are created even if **numpy** is not used. This happens only for a moment but each sub-process receives a copy of the objects allocated in memory. It is not a big deal, since it happens at the very beginning, but I am worried about any possible side-effect. Could someone explain me why this is happening?

Here very simple piece code to reproduce the problem:

```
import time
import numpy

def hello_world():
    print("Hello world")
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Running")
    time.sleep(30)
    hello_world()
```

Comment: The easiest way to get an answer is probably to read the source ([link](https://github.com/numpy/numpy))

Comment: Turns out the previous comment is wrong. The fork is likely not happening in numpy proper but in a linear algebra library used by numpy, most likely MKL. See e.g. [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10060#issuecomment-381622451) comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by OpenBLAS. You can solve this by calling
`OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 python myscript.py`